# Dynamic Table Insert TSQL: Insert records into another table where schemas are Mismatched

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic

In an effort to efficiently move records from one table to another I'm struggling to write a T-SQL stored procedure to accomplish this task in a generic manner.

> **Requirements**:
>
> 1. Needs to be generic so that the specific columns are NOT hard coded into the Stored Procedure.
> 2. The only input parameters should be the names of the Source Table and Destination Table.
> 3. All Records from Source are Inserted Into Destination
> 4. For a given record we map over only the data from the matching columns from both tables
> 5. Columns missing from the source table will receive their Default Values in the Destination Table.
> 6. Data from any columns missing from the Destination table will simply be ignored

[There is one stackoverflow question similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401419/dynamic-table-insert-tsql), but they were trying to insert into staging tables based on the value of some datetime.  I felt it was necessary to post this as an original question since this would be a completely generic solution with no special conditions attached.

I know the solution will involve using Insert Into, any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: please post your attempt

Comment: What if the destination has a column that require a value and there is no matching column in the source?  What define matching columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this as a starting point for your stored proc:

```
DECLARE @SourceSchema SYSNAME = 'dbo'   --Assume dbo for demo purposes.
DECLARE @SourceTable SYSNAME = 'SourceTableName'
DECLARE @DestSchema SYSNAME = 'dbo' --Assume dbo for demo purposes.
DECLARE @DestTable SYSNAME = 'DestinationTableName'

DECLARE @Tsql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @Columns = @Columns + '[' + src.COLUMN_NAME + '],'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS src
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS dest
    ON src.COLUMN_NAME = dest.COLUMN_NAME
    --Assume you only want to insert data from src fields to dest fields if they're the same data type.
    --Data conversion is messy and outside the scope of the OP's question.
    AND src.DATA_TYPE = dest.DATA_TYPE 
WHERE src.TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema
AND src.TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable
AND dest.TABLE_SCHEMA = @DestSchema
AND dest.TABLE_NAME = @DestTable

SET @Columns = LEFT(@Columns, LEN(@Columns) - 1)
PRINT @Columns

SET @Tsql = 'INSERT INTO [' + @DestSchema + '].[' + @DestTable + ']' +
    '(' + @Columns + ')' +
    'SELECT ' + @Columns +
    'FROM [' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']'
PRINT @Tsql

--Uncomment when ready to proceed.
--EXEC (@TSql)
```